# I can't update my extension - SmartFoxServer

Tags: server-configuration, smartfoxserver

I am working with smartfoxserver 2X. I have problem with updating of extension's code. My extension name is: "MyFirstExtension". There is a .jar file in this folder named: MyFirstExtension.jar . The extension was tested and is working fine. Now I want to update my code. I open Eclipse and I add a few line of code to my project. I exported new code to new .jar and I override old .jar. After restarting a server I see that OLD code is run. I don't have any idea why. How the server could remember old code ? Is there a cache which I can delete ? How to resolve this problem ?

Thanks,
Tomek

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with SFS2X for a while and I am sure that every time you restart your server your extensions are reloaded. If you have 'reload mode' in 'Zone Extension Tab' set to auto, the extension will reload without restarting the server.

It seems that your doing everything right and because you've tested your extension, your export path must be right.
Double check that your export path is similar to the following
C:\Program Files\SmartFoxServer2X\SFS2X\extensions\MyFirstExtension\MyFirstExtension.jar

You could also try exporting to an alternative path and manually copy the file into your extension path. If it reloads the old extension then there would have to be another SFS2X server installation path.

Answer (score 0):

let me know one thing are you running smartfoxserver as a service base or not. In my view your service is still running in the background as on the updated extension jar is not working. So try this open services and stop the smartfoxserver and restart the sfs to che k the modification. Better to don't use service for smartfoxserver.